# Access function f of class A in class B, while f need to access member variable of B

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

consider the following code:

```
class Car 
{
public:
  bool openCar();
}

class LocomotiveEngineer
{
public: 
   bool carRepair();

private:
   std::list<int> m_screwdriver;  
   std::vector<int> m_keys; 
   Car myCar; 
}

int main() {
    LocomotiveEngineer peter;
}
```

What I'm trying to solve is to allow the implementations of `carRepair()` and `openCar()` to fulfill the following 2 conditions:

- `carRepair()` calls `openCar()`
- `openCar()` can access `m_keys` and `m_screwdriver`. (Via an instance of LocomotiveEngineer or whatever)

That means in the cpp of LocomotiveEngineer I want to do something likes:

```
LocomotiveEngineer::carRepair() 
{
  openCar();     //carRepair() calls openCar()
}
```

and in the cpp of Car I have something likes:

```
Car::openCar()
{
   m_keys.size();             //openCar() can access m_keys via an instance of LocomotiveEngineer or whatever
   m_screwdriver.empty();   //openCar() can access m_screwdriver via an instance of LocomotiveEngineer or whatever
}
```

How can I design that? I'm constangly getting errors. I think I muss use things like: class forward declaration, friend, etc
Thanks in advance. 
ps: I'm limited to c++11

Comment: You can't call `openCar()` from `carRepair()`, there is no object to call it on.

Comment: @Evgeny then an object should be created if this is the right way to do that. I have let things open, such that one can propose how to design the whole

Comment: It should. But it is up to you to decide where it should be created. I guess you lack full understanding of OOP in C++. Even a simple book on the subject will do you much good.

Comment: Creating an object will not solve the problem presented here. I'm doing with oop pretty well

Comment: The most obvious solution is to pass the keys and the screwdriver as parameters to `openCar` instead.

Comment: You have left this question a bit too open. There are countless of ways to go about it. A good starting point could be to consider ownership. You will have Cars and Locomotiveengeneers in your program. Where will the instance live in your code base? Or to put it in other word. Who is in charge of creating and destroying cars and engineers?

Comment: @super `LocomotiveEngineer`  has a `Car` instance as member variable, and `LocomotiveEngineer` is instanciate in main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the car as `friend` to the LocomotiveEngineer class:

```
class LocomotiveEngineer
{
public: 
    bool carRepair();

private:
   std::list<int> m_screwdriver;  
   std::vector<int> m_keys;

friend class Car;
}
```

But then you have to have an instance of an Lokomotive Engineer of course
or declare the Engineers variables as static;

If you want to further specify the `friend` keyword, you can also only friend a specific function and not the whole class with `friend bool Car::openCar();` instead of `friend class Car;`

**Working Example**

**Header:**

```
#include <vector>
class LocomotiveEngineer; // forward declare

class Car 
{
public:
  bool openCar(LocomotiveEngineer& repairmen); 
}

class LocomotiveEngineer
{
public: 
   bool carRepair(Car& broken_car); //specify the car whcih needs to be repaired

private:
   std::list<int> m_screwdriver;  
   std::vector<int> m_keys;

friend class Car;
}
```

**cpp:**

```
bool  LocomotiveEngineer::carRepair(Car& broken_car) 
{
  broken_car.openCar(*this);
  return true;
}

bool  Car::openCar(LocomotiveEngineer& repairmen){
    repairmen.m_keys.size();             //openCar() can access m_keys
    repairmen.m_screwdriver.empty();   //openCar() can access m_screwdriver
    return true;
}
```

**main***

```
int main(){
    Car brokenCar;
    LocomotiveEngineer bob;

    bob.carRepair(brokenCar);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> I have to note, this way to do the job is not a good design, but sufficient for the beginning

Comment: it doesn't work. On the other side, Engineers variable as static is not a good idea, they can only be initialize later on in the framework

Comment: It works. You need one instance of an `LocomotiveEngineer` to acces its members. e.g. `myEngineer->m_keys.size()`

Comment: I'm trying it and it doesn't works. Can you post the code which is working for you?

Comment: ok it worked after forward declarating LocomotiveEngineer  (class LocomotiveEngineer;) in the header, and changing `broken_car->openCar(*this);`   to `broken_car.openCar(*this);`  in  `LocomotiveEngineer::carRepair`